# can't add GPU to GCP AI platform Notebooks instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Good afternoon.

I have encountered one problem when I tried to add GPU(NVIDIA Tesla T4) to an instance of GCP AI platform Notebooks.

The thing I want to do is to start an instance with GPU. But it doesn't work and GCP says

> There are no GPUs available for the zone, framework and machine type of this instance.

And when I started an instance, it says

> riiid: The zone 'projects/adept-rock-292801/zones/asia-northeast1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

[Problem Occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGW8w.png)

---

**CHECKPOINT 1**

I've checked Admin Quota and here's the setting. I guess there's no problem with that.

```
GPUs (all regions): limit 1
NVIDIA T4 GPUs - asia-northeast1: limit 1
```

---

**CHECKPOINT 2**

There is only one instance that I have created so far. So no other instances use quota limit.

---

**CHECKPOINT 3**

This following link says NVIDIA Tesla T4 is available in Zone `asia-northeast1-a`, so I guess availability zone is not the factor of this problem.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones

---

**CHECKPOINT 4**

My instance's machine type is now `4 vCPUs, 15 GB RAM(* n1-standard-4)` so there should be no problem in regards to the machine type, according to the following link.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus

---

Why is GPU not available with this situation? Does anyone give me a tip to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Machine type? E2 ? N1? Check this link and verify your machine type supports GPU. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types, have you tried with other GPU type? For example P100 ?

Comment: @gogasca Thank you for your message. I am using `n1-standard-4` and there is no option to select GPU type but None.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed by a Public Issue Tracker case, [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/168028227). Since you are still experiencing it, you can leave a comment there and describe how you are experiencing the issue. Thus, the case will be re-opened.

However, there is a workaround. In order to be able to add a GPU to an AI platform Notebook instance after it is creation, follow the steps below:

1. Create an instance selecting `Python 3 (CUDA Toolkit 11.0)` and option  `without GPU`;
2. Go to Compute engine and select your VM;
3. Stop the VM and click edit;
4. Under **Machine configuration**, go to **GPU type** and add the desired type of GPU;
5. Save the changes and start your VM;
6. **SSH** into it and you will be prompted to install the *nvidia drivers*;
7. If you are not prompt, use the following command to install the drivers: `sudo /opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh`;
8. Confirm the installation of the drivers with `nvidia-smi`;

Please pay attention to the notes below:

- If you have a firewall rule, the port 22 should be whitelisted. You can use the command `gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22` to do so.
- It is highly advisable to spread your work load across multiple regions, [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps);
- Currently, you seem to be using the GPUs instances on demand without the guarantee of capacity since the zone can be depleted. For this reason, if you want to guarantee your resources you can use a feature called [Reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources), which ensures that the resources are available for your workloads when you need them;

Comment: Thanks for you message and additional tips about firewall. I could installed nvidia driver to vm instance by following your instruction, but it seems that my AI platform notebook doesn't have the driver. I opened JUPYTERLAB and command **nvidia-smi** on terminal but it shows **command not found**. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you run the command `sudo /opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh` successfully? The command has to be run in the terminal the same as you installed the drivers. I must point that your VM must be with Python 3( CUDA Toolkit 11.0), with the option without GPU selected. This environment will allow you to run the commands I specified above.

Comment: I ran the command and worked on vm instance, nvidia-smi was also working, but nvidia-smi was not working on terminal of AI platform notebook. One of my friends told me that this problem happens when **GCP itself has no resource** at all. I think it seems right. I re-created new instance in the morning and I successfully started an instance with GPU.

Comment: I could overcome this problem thanks to all the comments you sent me. Thank you so much.